# Allow optional object to use class extension function Swift

Tags: swift

I'm not sure how to construct the question in a much more proper way, and there are quite similar questions but they don't exactly give me an answer.

What I wanna do is pretty much simple. I have a model:

```
struct Person: Codable {

...
    // And I have a func, or let's put it in an extension:

    func isEqual(to person: Person?) -> Bool {
      return self.id == person?.id
    }

}
```

And it's used like this, no brainer:

```
let person1: Person!
let person2: Person?
person1.isEqual(to: person2)
```

But I need the function to accept the first object as optional, like so:

```
let person1: Person?
let person2: Person?
person1?.isEqual(to: person2)
```

So question is, how to make such function accepts a first object as optional?

Comment: Could you show us where do you want to use that call? Because the call itself (`person1?.isEqual(to: person2)`) should work. I suspect that the context in which you want to use it doesn't accept this.

Comment: The `.distinctUntilChanged()`'s block in `RxSwift` gives you two optional objects.

Comment: Ok, got that, but I am asking the exact line where you want to use this call, because if you want to do for instance `if person1?.isEqual(to: person2) ...`, this should give you an error indeed. Note that `person1?.isEqual(to: person2)` returns a `Bool?`, not a `Bool`, despite the return type of your `isEqual(to:)` method.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, if `person1` is nil what would you call? You can create a static method that takes 2 objects but not call an instance method

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think it makes sense as long as you unwrap the optionals. If `person1` is nil then the call returns nil as well. The `isEqual(to:)` method won't even be executed. But yeah, you have to take that into account if you really want to skip the optional unwrapping part.

Comment: @VladRusu But the question is how to call (execute) the function when person1 is nil and that doesn't make sense to me, unless of course I have misunderstood it ;).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I see your point :)). I didn't take the question text that literally. What I understood from the question is how to make that method call not illegal, not how to really call that method regardless of the fact that `person1` might be nil.

Comment: Why don't you conform `Person` to `Equatable` and just do `person1 == person2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to extend the `Optional` enum with a condition for the generic parameter `Wrapped`

This is what it would look like

```
class User: Codable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
    var age: Int

    ...

    func isEqual(to user: User) -> Bool {
        return self.id == user.id
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == User {
    func isEqual(to user: User?) -> Bool {
        return self?.id == user?.id
    }
}
```

And since the method is on different types `Optional` and `User`, you can use the dot notation without using Optional chaining. Example

```
let user1: User? = nil
let user2: User? = nil
let bool = user1.isEqual(to: user2)
```

Comment: Bingo! I was trying to do such way but somehow I got lost, and ended up asking a downvote-worthy question.

Answer (score 3):

You ask:

> So question is, how to make such function accepts a first object as optional?

By “first object”, I guess you mean `person1` in your example.

You can’t make the function accept the “first object“ (the receiver, `person1`) as optional. The function is defined on type `Person`, but `person1` has type `Optional<Person>`.

What you **can** do is **also** define the method on `Optional<Person>`, like this:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Person {
    func isEqual(to person: Person?) -> Bool {
        // If I’m `.some`, call through to my wrapped value’s isEqual(to:).
        // If I’m nil, I’m only equal to person if person is also nil.
        return self?.isEqual(to: person) ?? (person == nil)
    }
}
```

With this method (and your existing `isEqual(to:)` defined on `Person`), you can call `isEqual(to:)` on both a `Person` and a `Person?`.

Comment: Sorry. I messed up the type constraint in my original answer (I wrote `Wrapped: Person`). I have fixed it (it’s now `Wrapped == Person`). This should allow `Person` to be a `struct`.